# Find the index of first non-negative element in each column of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 35000*200 matrix and want to determine the index of first non-negative element of each column in matlab. Specifically, at the output I want a 1*200 vector where each element is the row index of the first non-negative element in the corresponding column.

Thanks.
Sajjad

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - we will help you with code problems, but we won't write it for you. Show the code you have tried, and any errors you get if you want help

Answer (score 3):

You can use `max` over logicals. If your data is in matrix `A`, and you want your result in vector `i`:

```
[M, i] = max(A >= 0, [], 1); % we find the first non-negative value per column.
i(~M) = 0; % if all values are negative in that column, we output 0 for it.
```